# Playing audio clip through media player using Uri

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

In my application, I am getting the list of audio files present externally and playing the first file using the `Uri` of that file. I have written the following code for it.

```
public class ScrSettings extends Activity{
private Uri uriString;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);

    Button playsong = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_me);
    playsong.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            uriString = getFirstSongUri();
            Log.i("Uri is : ", uriString.toString());

            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(); 
            try {
                mp.setDataSource(ScrSettings.this, uriString); 
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            mp.start();
        }
    }); 
}
private Uri getFirstSongUri() {
    Cursor media = null;
    String songTitle = "";
    try {
        // query for the numbers associated with the contact
        media = getContentResolver().query(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);

        while (media.moveToNext()) {
            songTitle = media.getString(media.getColumnIndex(Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
            Uri uri = Media.getContentUri(songTitle);
            return uri;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MediaList", "Failed to get email data", e);
    } finally {
        if (media != null) {
            media.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And it also logs the song's Uri in the logcat but it does not play the file and I get the following exception.

```
02-23 16:06:19.038: W/System.err(1890): java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.: status=0x80000000
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:800)
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:725)
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at com.raj.poc.test.ScrSettings$1.onClick(ScrSettings.java:51)
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2532)
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9293)
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-23 16:06:19.058: W/System.err(1890):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-23 16:06:19.068: W/System.err(1890):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-23 16:06:19.068: W/System.err(1890):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anybody please tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I just had the same error status on setDataSource failure and it means that the format of the media file is not understood by MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

for audio you must use **MediaStore.Audio...**

```
media .getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE));
```

also have a [look here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Audio.html)